# What is the regex to extract a date mask in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string in perl that contains a directory specification.  If the string contains any individual or combination of substrings that comprise a date mask, I want to extract that substring.  For example, the directory spec may be:

```
/mydir/data/YYYYMMDD
```

I want to be able to extract the "YYYYMMDD" string.  However that portion of the path could be any individual or combination of the following strings:

```
YY
YYYY
MM
DD
```

So the directory spec string could read:

```
   /mydir/data/DD/data2
```

and I want the "DD" returned as a result of the regex comparison.   How do I capture the string when it must contain one or more of those date mask strings and that string must be between two "/" characters or exist at the end of the string?

Comment: Do you mean to match literal characters `YY`, `DD` etc, or numbers representing dates?

Comment: @TLP Good question! My solution works with numbers, but it might not be what GregH wanted.

Comment: I deleted my not-fully-working solution, so here's a "hint" —      `m{/((YYYY|YY|MM|DD){1,})/}` is close, but doesn't handle end-of-strings, and also not in cases like "YYYY/MM/" I don't think. But maybe helpful.

Comment: So you really wanted to manipulate the mask characters and not the values they would represent.  At least two of us took it as the later. I'd be interested in hearing the reason for your query in the context you need it.  I've deleted my suggestion, accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I'm making the assumption that `YYYY` and `YY` shall not both appear in the same pattern, because otherwise it does not make sense.

```
use Data::Munge qw(list2re);
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(variations);
use Perl6::Take qw(gather take);

list2re
uniq
gather {
    for my $n ([qw(YYYY MM DD)], [qw(YY MM DD)]) {
        for my $k (1..scalar @$n) {
            take map { join q(), @$_ } variations($n, $k)
        }
    }
}
```

The expression returns the regex `(?^:DDMMYYYY|DDYYYYMM|MMDDYYYY|MMYYYYDD|YYYYDDMM|YYYYMMDD|DDMMYY|DDYYMM|DDYYYY|MMDDYY|MMYYDD|MMYYYY|YYDDMM|YYMMDD|YYYYDD|YYYYMM|DDMM|DDYY|MMDD|MMYY|YYDD|YYMM|YYYY|DD|MM|YY)`. (Semi-)Functional programming for the win!

Comment: Is the *"semi"* because of the `for` loops ;)?

Comment: Yeah, it would be fuglier with `map` because we need two extra lines for copying `$_` to a lexical variable in standard Perl, lack of Algol-style parameters be cursed. - This is already as short as possible without pulling in perl5i.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that there is only one "date" component, or if not, that you want the 1st one:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @paths = qw(
    /mydir/data/YYYYMMDD
    /mydir/data/YY/data2
    /mydir/data/YYMM/data2
    /mydir/data/DD/data2
);

foreach my $path (@paths) {
    my($date) = grep /^(([YMD])\2)+$/, split '/', $path;
    print "$path: $date\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the mask fields are always in the order Y - M - D, this will do what you need:

```
my ($mask) = $path =~ m{ / ( (?:YY){0,2} (?:MM)? (?:DD)? ) (?:/|$) }x;
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I'd use</strike>

```
my ($date) = m{/([0-9]{2,8})(?:/|$)}
```

and check whether

```
not(length($date) % 2)   # $date has even length
```

and maybe some checks for valid combinations.

**Update:** OK, to just get the mask, not the numbers, you can change this to

```
my ($date) = m{/([YMD]{2,8})(?:/|$)};
my $check = $date;
$check =~ s/YYYY/y/;
$check =~ s/MM//;
$check =~ s/DD//;
print "Matches $date\n" if grep $_ eq $check, (q{}, 'y', 'YY');
```

This should exclude all invalid combinations like YYDDYY or YYYYMMYY and so on.

Comment: The string inside the directory spec does not contain numbers.  It actually contains the alphabetic characters I listed (MM, DD, YY, YYYY).  I need to extract the substring containing those characters.